# How to Convert a Flattened Array to Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to convert the key values of an array into a multi-dimensional array. The key values look to be multidimensional, but are just text. I have tried exploding the the string and creating a new array, but I feel there must be something simpler than just that.

Example Below:

```
Array (
[Template[URL]] => http://www.asdasdda.com
[Template[UPC]] => 5484548546314
[Field[value]] =>  Test Example
[Field[answer]] => 20 )
```

All help is very much appricated. :)

UPDATE:
This is the exact output of the data before I run json_decode on the data.

```
{"Template[URL]":"http://www.asdasdda.com","Template[UPC]":"5484548546314","Field[value]":"Test Example","Field[answer]":"20"}
```

Comment: Can't fix it where the array is being created?

Comment: this surely shall work out if yr representation *Template[URL]* held a string value.  What is this *Template[URL]*? It is not a variable.. if *Template* was an array, then refer it appropriate - like: *$Template['URL']*

Comment: @Devon This comes in from an API from another department in my company, and the person who built this is impossibly hard to work with, so I rather just try and convert it. The funny thing is he sent it through as json, but didnt encode the multidimensional array, just flattened it.

Comment: @animaacija the key value of the arrays is formatted 'Template[URL]' not Template['URL']. That's the problem I am currently having.

Comment: maybe it is not an array but stdClass or smth? Where this comes from? What is *URL* then? Constant? if so , it has to have value in it.

Comment: @animaacija This is an array, this is the output of print_r from a json_decode with true enable for array output.

Comment: can you paste the actual string returned by the API?

Comment: @dbinns66 Exact output of API Request is posted above in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddled around for a bit, and I think I got it. I don't think there is any simpler way:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    preg_match("/\[(.+)\]/",$key,$match);
    $newKey = preg_replace("/\[.+\]/","",$key);
    $newArray[$newKey][$match[1]] = $value;
}
```

Where a `print_r()` of `$newArray` is as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [Template] => Array ( 
        [URL] => http://www.asdasdda.com 
        [UPC] => 5484548546314 
        ) 
    [Field] => Array ( 
        [value] => Test Example 
        [answer] => 20 
        ) 
    )
```

Comment: If you only have single level, for instance Template[URL], then this will work great.  If you ever have multiple levels, for instance Template[1][URL], then you can consult my answer's use of references in a loop.

Comment: @KevinWeber ^ above comment was supposed to be directed at you.

Comment: @Devon Thank you Devon, I will be bookmarking this page for future use of these scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The problem should probably be addressed where the array is being created.  If you don't have access to that, then you can use a regex with a reference loop to convert the array:

```
$array = [
"Template[URL]" => 'http://www.asdasdda.com',
"Template[UPC]" => '5484548546314',
"Multi[Level][Array]" => 'Hello World'
];

function convert(&$array, $key, $value) {
   preg_match_all("/(?=^)[^]]+(?=\[)|(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])/", $key, $keys);
   if ($keys = $keys[0]) {
       // Unset original key
       unset($array[$key]);
       // Dig into each level of keys and reassign the reference
       foreach($keys as $key) {
           if (!isset($array[$key])) $array[$key] = null;
           $array = &$array[$key];
       }
       // Set the final level equal to the original value
       $array = $value;
   }
}

foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   convert($array, $key, $value);
}

print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Template] => Array
        (
            [URL] => http://www.asdasdda.com
            [UPC] => 5484548546314
        )

    [Multi] => Array
        (
            [Level] => Array
                (
                    [Array] => Hello World
                )

        )

)
```

References are used so you can dig into multiple levels if you should need.