# How to convert singledimensional array to multidimensional php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => product
    [1] => id
    [2] => name
    [3] => 
    [4] => type
    [5] => productID
    [6] => name
)
```

and I'd like to convert to use the empty value as a seperator, something like

```
[0]=>[[0][1][2]]
[1]=>[[4][5][6]]
```

I tried using the answer in this [How to Convert a Flattened Array to Multidimensional Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803447/how-to-convert-a-flattened-array-to-multidimensional-array-in-php) post, but didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Maybe you should look at where you create this array and make the array correctly at that point.

Comment: Please add the code you tried to the question itself. Do not simply ask for a solution without providing your own effort.

Comment: What is the value in `[3]`? `null`, `false`, `''`? `print_r` is a piece of trash. Use `echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
  $arr = array('product','id','name','','type','productID','name');
  $newArray = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value!=''){
      $newArray[$i][$key]= $value;
    }else{
      $i++;
    }
  }
  print_r($newArray);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, works great! Will accept this answer in 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
$arr=Array
(
    "product",
    "id",
    "name",
    "",
    "type",
    "productID",
    "name",
);

$newarr=array();
$j=0;

for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($arr); $i++) { 
    if ($arr[$i]!=="") {
        $newarr[$j][$i]=$arr[$i];
    }else{
        $j++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newarr);
```